# How can I turn a pointer to an object to a constant dereferenced object?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, constants

I am trying to write a toString function for a linked list of Student pointers, implementing a previously created toString function from Student class.

My issue is that as I traverse through the linked list, I'm having trouble creating each Student object in order to call toString from Student class.

I supposed it has to do with the fact that I need a const &Student parameter when constructing a new Student object, but I don't know how change each temp->s to constant &Stud. Can I use const_cast, like shown below?

This is what I have so far:

```
std::string StudentRoll::toString() const {
  Node* temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL){ //my attempt
        Student newStudent(const_cast <Student*> (temp->s));
        *(newStudent).toString(); //toString function from Student class            
        temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```

This is my Student.h :

```
#include <string>

class Student {

 public:
  Student(const char * const name, int perm);

  int getPerm() const;
  const char * const getName() const;

  void setPerm(const int perm);
  void setName(const char * const name);

  Student(const Student &orig);
  ~Student();
  Student & operator=(const Student &right);

  std::string toString() const;

 private:
  int perm;
  char *name; // allocated on heap
};
```

And this is StudentRoll.h

```
#include <string>
#include "student.h"

class StudentRoll {

 public:
  StudentRoll();
  void insertAtTail(const Student &s);
  std::string toString() const;

  StudentRoll(const StudentRoll &orig);
  ~StudentRoll();
  StudentRoll & operator=(const StudentRoll &right);

 private:
  struct Node {
    Student *s;
    Node *next;
  };
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
};
```

Comment: No need to make a copy, just do `temp->s->toString()`

Comment: A `const` parameter just indicates that the function will not modify the object.  You do not have to cast to `const` in order to pass it in, just the deference should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const_cast` *removes* const-ness, so you wouldn't want to use that in this case.

Since `Node`'s `s` field is a `Student*`, you just dereference it (`*` operator) to extract a `Student` object.  When passed to the constructor for `Student`, the `const &` is implicit.

Try the following, with understanding that you need to return a value from `StudentRoll::toString()`.

```
std::string StudentRoll::toString() const {
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){ //my attempt 
        Student newStudent(*(temp->s));
        newStudent.toString(); //toString function from Student class            
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!